# Have any scholars believed that devas are morally infallible?

Tags: gods, philosophy, dharma, sin, shad-darshana

Are there any theologians throughout history who have held that the devas are incapable of sinning?

Can anyone find any quotations from scholars expressing such a view?

Even if you disagree and think that devas can sin, please provide quotes that say otherwise.

Comment: please use hindu rather than christian questions in your terminology. 'Sinning" is a christian concept. In Hinduism there is karma. New karma is only accumulated during an earthly existence. When a jiva is a deva, it is not capable if accumulating new karma, only using karma gained during an earthly existence.

Comment: So if devas cannot accumulate karma, and if karma accumulates from moral choices, does that mean devas cannot make moral choices?